# How to evaluate a mobile app using ISO/IEC 25010:2011?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, evaluation, iso, usability, portal

The project I want to develop is the Student Portal Mobile APP using Hybrid frameworks (Ionic4, Angular, Cordova).
My problem is I do not know how to evaluate its usability, functionality, reliability, and software evaluation tools using the ISO/IEC 25010:2011. Thank you very much!